# Get ContentControl by title (or tag)

Tags: vba, ms-word

`Document.ContentControls` collection doesn't support item retrieval by name, only by index.

Can I still get a specific `ContentControl` by a user-defined identifier so as to keep code readable? (e.g. [Content control titles - Ms Office Forums](http://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/13080-content-control-titles.html) claims it's only possible to try them one by one.)

Comment: The information you have is correct, and a solution is offered at the link you posted. It is really very fast to loop through a collection like this. The answer provided below applies to Office 365 and may not be available in your version of MS Office.

Comment: @Variatus I'm currently using the solution in the answer in Office 2007.

Comment: Then you have the best available. Why do you complain about it? It should be a separate function in your code which you install once and forget how it does its job.

Comment: @Variatus installing a convenience function (and one using a highly suboptimal algorithm) into each and every Office document I'm dealing with just because I'm too lazy to check if the app developers already prepared something better for me is not my idea of the best approach to product use.

Comment: @Variatus Besides, maybe I wasn't clear enough in my first reply. I'm currently using the solution from my answer in Office 2007. Since this is the version that introduced Content Controls in the first place, this means those methods are available in all Office versions that have Content Controls.

Comment: Sorry, I got my bearings mixed. You mean to say that the `SelectContentControlByTitle()` function is available in VBA versions other (and earlier) than Office 365?

Comment: @Variatus Exactly. I only linked to Office 365 version of online help because it's the best one that I found (and didn't find a help page for all versions) and I assumed that the functions are exactly the same in all versions, so it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are [`Document.SelectContentControlsByTitle()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/document-selectcontentcontrolsbytitle-method-word) and [`Document.SelectContentControlsByTag()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/document-selectcontentcontrolsbytag-method-word) methods for this.

Since neither property of a control is guaranteed to be unique, both return a `ContentControls` collection of results. A function like this can be used to verify that the result exists and is unique:

```
Public Function CCSingle(source As ContentControls) As ContentControl
    Select Case Sgn(source.Count - 1)
    Case -1
        '9 = subscript out of range
        'http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9781118257616.app3/pdf
        Call Err.Raise(9, , "Identifier not found")
    Case 1
        Call Err.Raise(9, , "Identifier not unique")
    Case Else
        Set CCSingle = source.Item(1)
    End Select
End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

Content Controls can be identified by their `.Tag` property and their `.Title` property. Here is something simplistic. It returns  the first Content Control from the set of all Content Controls that matches both a Title and Tag.

```vb
Function FindCCbyTitleAndTag (Title as string, Tag as string) as ContentControl
  Dim CC as ContentControl
  For each CC in ActiveDocument.ContentControls
    If CC.Title = Title and CC.Tag = Tag then
      FindCCbyTitleAndTag = CC
    End If
  Next CC
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Content Control is inside a Text Box, you need to loop through shapes as well. Here I extended the answer from @Bruce M. I added a simple check for result existance.

```vb
Function FindCCbyTitleAndTag(Title As String, Tag As String) As ContentControl
  Dim CC As ContentControl
  Dim sh As shape
  
  For Each CC In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
    If CC.Tag = Tag And CC.Title = Title Then
      Set FindCCbyTitleAndTag = CC
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next CC
  
  For Each sh In ActiveDocument.Shapes
    For Each CC In sh.TextFrame.TextRange.ContentControls
      If CC.Tag = Tag And CC.Title = Title Then
        Set FindCCbyTitleAndTag = CC
        Exit Function
      End If
    Next CC
  Next sh
  
  Set FindCCbyTitleAndTag = Nothing
End Function
```