# If one combobox is changed, set the other comboboxes to specific items

Tags: vba, ms-word

I created five comboboxes directly in Word (not in a userform).
Each combobox has its own title (e.g., item1, item2, item3, item4, item5).

I found a way to identify which ContentControl has been changed.

```vb
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox (ContentControl.Title)
End sub
```

How do I set the other comboboxes to specific items based on the change in the first combobox?

Comment: Content control by title: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46009985/get-contentcontrol-by-title-or-tag

Comment: Wow~ you are so~~ great, thank you!!

Comment: But after finding the content control, how can I change the value of that content control if the content control is a combobox?

Answer (score 0):

In Word the ActiveX `ComboBox` selected item can be reached through the `Range` property.

This property can be set to any text, but this not become an item of the ComboBox only will be displayed in the listbox of it.

This is an example of it:

```
Dim box1 As ContentControl, box2 As ContentControl

Sub combos()
Dim doc As Document
Set doc = ActiveDocument

Set box1 = doc.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlComboBox)
doc.Range.InsertAfter vbLf & vbLf
Set box2 = doc.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlComboBox, doc.Range(doc.Range.End - 1))
box1.DropdownListEntries.Add "box1.one"
box1.DropdownListEntries.Add "box1.two"
box1.DropdownListEntries.Add "box1.three"
box2.DropdownListEntries.Add "box2.one"
box2.DropdownListEntries.Add "box2.two"
box2.DropdownListEntries.Add "box2.three"
box2.DropdownListEntries.Add "box2.four"
box1.SetPlaceholderText , , "Select in box1"
box2.SetPlaceholderText , , "Select in box2"

End Sub



Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)

If box1 Is Nothing Then
For Each concont In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
If concont.PlaceholderText = "Select in box1" Then Set box1 = concont
If concont.PlaceholderText = "Select in box2" Then Set box2 = concont
Next concont
End If

If box1.Range = "box1.one" Then box2.Range = box2.DropdownListEntries(3)
If box1.Range = "box1.two" Then box2.Range = box2.DropdownListEntries(1)

End Sub
```

Select in the first combo an item and click somewhere on the document. The second combo's text will change to the defined entry.

The first Sub only for test purposes to create the combos on the document.

The event procedure is the one what you need if you have manually created the combos. Change the placeholdertext equation to the one you have in the combos. Extend the code to the desired number of combos by repeating the if statements according to the desired values.

Comment: Thank you, Black cat, it is very helpful.